# Create Table with check constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Could someone please explain how the results would differ (what are the benefits) between the two CREATE table statements?

**Option #1**

```
 CREATE TABLE sch.address_type (
  address_type_cd VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT sch_2002 CHECK ("address_type_cd" IS NOT NULL),
  desc_txt VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT sch_2003 CHECK ("DESC_TXT" IS NOT NULL),
  rec_creat_ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL CONSTRAINT sch_2001 CHECK ("REC_CREAT_TS" IS NOT NULL),
  CONSTRAINT pk_address_type PRIMARY KEY (address_type_cd)
);
```

**Option #2**

```
CREATE TABLE sch.address_type (
  address_type_cd VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  desc_txt VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  rec_creat_ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_address_type PRIMARY KEY (address_type_cd)
);
```

Thanks

Comment: The `check` constraints are utterly unnecessary.  Why would you include them?

Comment: The difference is that, if you alter the table to remove the NOT NULL designation on the columns, the check constraints from the first version will still be in place. That will cause a lot of confusion. Now: Is this the question you meant to ask, or did you mean to ask something else? Namely, perhaps in the first query you did **not** mean to have the `NOT NULL`, and instead only wanted the `CHECK` constraints?

Comment: I'm using a comparison tool between two database environments and one environment is showing as the first create statement while the second is showing the one without the check constraints.  Was curious if there was an advantage to the first - it did seem redundant to have both in the first example...

Comment: Your comparison tool is incorrectly adding unnecessary constraint clauses when it detects `NOT NULL` columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the constraints created using the query:

```
SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type, search_condition
FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE table_name = 'ADDRESS_TYPE';
```

**Option 1**:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME      C SEARCH_CONDITION             
-------------------- - ------------------------------
PK_ADDRESS_TYPE      P 
SYS_C0010366         C "ADDRESS_TYPE_CD" IS NOT NULL
SYS_C0010367         C "DESC_TXT" IS NOT NULL
SYS_C0010368         C "REC_CREAT_TS" IS NOT NULL
SCH_2002             C address_type_cd IS NOT NULL
SCH_2003             C "DESC_TXT" IS NOT NULL
SCH_2001             C "REC_CREAT_TS" IS NOT NULL
```

**Option 2**:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME      C SEARCH_CONDITION             
-------------------- - ------------------------------
PK_ADDRESS_TYPE      P 
SYS_C0010373         C "ADDRESS_TYPE_CD" IS NOT NULL
SYS_C0010374         C "DESC_TXT" IS NOT NULL
SYS_C0010375         C "REC_CREAT_TS" IS NOT NULL
```

**Option 3**:

```
CREATE TABLE address_type (
  address_type_cd VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)  CONSTRAINT address_type__cd__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  desc_txt        VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) CONSTRAINT address_type__desc__nn NOT NULL,
  rec_creat_ts    TIMESTAMP          DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                     CONSTRAINT address_type__rct__nn NOT NULL
);
```

Has the constraints:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME           C SEARCH_CONDITION             
------------------------- - ------------------------------
ADDRESS_TYPE__CD__PK      P 
ADDRESS_TYPE__DESC__NN    C "DESC_TXT" IS NOT NULL
ADDRESS_TYPE__RCT__NN     C "REC_CREAT_TS" IS NOT NULL
```

So:

- Option 1 creates 7 constraints of which there are 3 pairs of duplicate constraints (where each pair has a user-named and a system-named constraint)
- Option 2 creates 4 constraints (getting rid of the duplicate user-named constraints, leaving the system named constraints)
- Option 3 creates only 3 constraints - a `NOT NULL` constraint is unnecessary on a `PRIMARY KEY` column and it also names the `NOT NULL` constraints.

All the options will give the same effective result. Naming your constraints is useful during debugging (even the `NOT NULL` constraints)

Answer (score 1):

Both statements do the same function, but in first query you are doing unnecessary effort. i.e `address_type_cd VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL` is same as `CONSTRAINT sch_2002 CHECK ("address_type_cd" IS NOT NULL),` . Both of them mean there should a value in the field and cant be equal to `NULL`